# Missing First Character In Printing Array (While Loop)

Tags: c

Very simple question. Why is the first letter cutting off? Prints "harles" going down. I see that I can hard code a fix with `x = -1` but defeats the purpose of truly understanding what the underlying issue is and knowing solutions. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    char iArray[7] = 'Charles';

    while (x < 7) {
        x++;
        printf("%c\n", iArray[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you increment the `x` before indexing into the array? You probably meant `iArray[x++]`.

Comment: When iterating over an array, it's almost always better to use a `for` loop, as then the index variable will be initialized, checked and incremented in the correct order.

Comment: And there are a few other problems with your code as well: First the use of single-quotes for the string; Secondly the size of the array will not be enough to store the string *with the **null terminator***.

Comment: For me the most interesting question is why it prints "harles" at all. You initialize your array with a multibyte character constant instead of a string.

Comment: Worked perfectly with the for loop. Sorry about the formatting. I tend to code with proper indentation but it came out weird and couldn't revise it.

Comment: Array indexing is 0-based in C. The 1st element is `iArray[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

You are first incrementating the index, then using it to print.

```
x++;
printf("%c\n", iArray[x]);
```

Changing to

```
printf("%c\n", iArray[x]);
x++;
```

will fix that problem and also avoid UB for accessing beyond the array.
The second mentioned problem occurs when the loop condition is still true for `x==6` and the index is then incremented to 7, which accesses `iArray[7]`. That is beyond the array because the highest legally accessable index in an array of size 7 is index 6.

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x = 0;
        char iArray[7] = 'Charles';

        while (x < 7) {
            printf("%c\n", iArray[x]);
            x++;//increment after printing
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: if its solve your problem then mark it as solution 
happy coding :)

Comment: The single quotes mean that this behaviour is implementation defined.

Comment: What is this `... = 'Charles';`?! These single quotes are a copypasta typo, right?

Answer (score 2):

You have increment x by 1 beforing using it, so x[0] will never print, x[0] contains 'C'. Increment the index 'x' after using it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    char iArray[7] = "Charles";

    while (x < 7) {
        printf("%c\n", iArray[x]);
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```